# Nonlinear differential coupled equations

Tags: matlab, differential-equations, boundary

I was wondering if anyone would tell me if it is possible to solve the coupled equations shown  in the attachment using matlab?
I defined first the function of the three equations

```
function  izero= coupled(z,x)
kappa=0.5;
izero=[-kappa*x(1)*(x(2)-x(3));-kappa*x(1)*x(2);kappa*x(1)*x(3)];
end
```

[image: coupled nonlinear differential equations]

i want to use bvp4c however i do not have the boundary condition at z=0 for all of the three variables ?? What can I do?
Thank you

Comment: i added another function for initial guess

Comment: i added another function for initial guess
function res=bc(x1,x2,x3)
res=[x0(1),x1(2)-sqrt(2),x1(3)-sqrt(2)]
 then to solve it by
sol=bvpinit(linspace(0,1000,10),[4*sqrt(2) 0 0]);
sol=bvp4c(@coupled,@bc,sol);
plot(z,x(:,1),'b',z,x(:,2),'r',z,x(:,3),'k')
it did not work i am not sure why :(